# Pandas boxplot: differences in df.plot.box and df.boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boxplot

Let's suppose we have this sample `DataFrame`...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[["A", 2, 5, 1],
          ["A", 8, 1, 5],
          ["C", 2, 2, 1],
          ["C", 9, 7, 9],
          ["C", 6, 2, 5],
          ["C", 3, 8, 5],
          ["B", 8, 5, 2],
          ["B", 6, 1, 5],
          ["B", 6, 5, 3]],
    columns=["category", "feature1", "feature2", "feature3"]
)
```

...and I would like to have boxplots for the 3 features, grouped by category.

According to the documentation of `df.plot.box()`

> by : string or sequence
>
> Column in the DataFrame to group by.

I thought this should do the trick. However, `df.plot.box(by="category")` results in:

[image]

This is wrong, isn't it? It is definitely not grouped by `category`.

Also, doing `df.groupby("category").plot.box()` plots each of the individual groups rather than grouping by `category` and doing a joint plot:

[image]

Even more interesting is that `df.boxplot(by="category")`, which I thought should just be an alias, yields the correct result:

[image]

Why is that?